# IntelliJ Idea Package does not exist

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, build, compiler-errors

I had an error building a jar from my project (where an external library was not being found), so I followed a Stackoverflow answer to Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven.

Then the jar was successfully built.

I have since added a tiny bit of code and tried to recompile, however now IntelliJ cannot find my basic classes, it says package X does not exist. I only used two classes to amend my code, and both of these classes say "does not exist" during build/compilation/run. (I use 400 classes and only the two I have recently use are saying "does not exist".

I have tried to reverse all settings changes, and disabled "delegate IDE build actions to Maven", but it still says package does not exist for both of these classes.

I have even removed the JDK entirely and installed a fresh copy, but same error.

What has gone wrong, and what can I do?

Comment: It is extremely difficult to know what the problem is based on the textual information. I would only suggest either use maven for package/dependency management or do it with your IDE. Mixing both of them may cause such issues.

Comment: Have you tried to run "reload" from Maven tool window and "File | Invalidate Caches"?